# Strage Error net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github, vite, vercel

After deploy my reactjs code to vercel, i've got this error on my console

GET https://sushiku.vercel.app/Sushiku/assets/index-Bm3LEuNZ.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
sushiku.vercel.app/:12

GET https://sushiku.vercel.app/Sushiku/assets/index-BUKuLBIx.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
sushiku.vercel.app/:11

looking at my code again at index.html, i'm just realize that code just added after deploying to vercel

this is the script

```
<link rel="stylesheet" crossorigin href="/Sushiku/assets/index-Bm3LEuNZ.css">
```

when i click the link, the file was not found

how to solve this problem? i've been trying all the solutions from internet and still it doesnt worked

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've configured your project to have a [base path](https://vitejs.dev/guide/build#public-base-path) of `/Sushiku`. For example

```js
// vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'

export default defineConfig({
  base: '/Sushiku/',
})
```

But you appear to have deployed it into the `/` root path.

Either remove the `base` config from `vite.config.js` or deploy your application into the appropriate sub-directory.